# How to set variable in C#

Tags: c#, variables

How to make this works? :

```
private string KeyChar = "";

public void SetMyKey(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
     KeyChar = e.KeyCode; //ERROR
}

public void MyKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
     if (e.KeyCode = Keys.KeyChar) { //ERROR
          Function();
     }
}
```

Comment: First step: get a beginner’s book of C#. This code contains some telltale signs that this is necessary.

Comment: I recommend `Head First C#`. [Amazon Link](http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-C-Andrew-Stellman/dp/0596514824).

Comment: @Konrad he probably is. Who didn't make such mistakes at the beginning? He who is free of syntax errors throw the first downvote!

Comment: **Read** the error messages. They'll tell you *why* there's an error. The errors are common enough mistakes we've all made.

Comment: I flagged this question because it's pretty terrible. **Not** because it's newbie code, or too simple, but because it's just throwing code out there and saying `it's not work! how can fix it?!` - if OP can edit the question and say how it's not working and what he wants to accomplish that would make a much better question for everyone here who´s trying to learn. :)

Comment: @Aleadam I never said that making such mistakes is bad. Also, I did **not** downvote this question – why would I? The question is perfectly valid. At the same time we need to recognise that some questions cannot be answered without the help of a book. Sure, we can fix the erros in the above code but explaining how variables are used correctly goes beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Konrad You're absolutely right, and I never thought you downvoted it (indeed, it seems nobody did). My comment wasn't meant to be aggressive in any way. My apologies if you took it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using  a method, I would use a property - you'll also want to use the correct type here (Keys, instead of string).  In addition, you need to use `==` to check equality, since `=` is for assignment in C#:

```
public Keys KeyChar { get; set; }

public void MyKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == this.KeyChar) {
        Function();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) { //Thanks Reed!
```

You are assigning instead of comparing

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx

Comment: This is still not going to handle everything, as KeyCode is not a string...

Comment: @Reed indeed. I saw the assignment and I didn't double check the rest. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, operator `=` means assignment, and operator `==` means comparison:

```
if (a == b)
{
    a = 1;
    b = x;
}
```